# How to trigger a re render if Redux state holds an object and only a property of the object is changed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
export const slice = createSlice({
  name: "slice_name",
  initialState: {
    field_1: {a: 1, b: 2}
  },
  reducers: {
    
  },
});
```

If `field_1.a` is changed. how can I trigger hooks that listen for this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every component that selects the value of `a` will automatically rerender if this value changes. This is kind of the whole point of Redux.

```
const a = useSelector(state => state.slice_name.field_1.a);
```